# Can I 'override' Name for DataMember in Derived class?

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

I have to implement some protocol. All of xmls that I need to serialize(WCF contracts) have always two specified sections and one "content" section - e.g.:

First:

```
<X>
 <Y>
  <Content1/>
 </Y>
</X>
```

Second:

```
<X>
  <Y>
   <Content2/>
  </Y>
</X>
```

I want to use some generics, but then problem with node name appeared. 
I found this answer : [Serialization DataMember (name) override issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392702/serialization-datamember-name-override-issue) but it doesn't fit for me.

Code for my approach:

```
public class X<TContent>
{
     [DataMember]
     public Y<TContent> yName { get; set; }
}

public class Y<TContent>
{
     [DataMember]
     public virtual TContent Content { get; set; }
}
```

And then there is few "Content" classes like:

```
public sealed class Content1Class: Y<Content1>
{
    [DataMember(Name = nameof(Content1))]
    public override Content1 Content { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately I have always null for Content.

My question is: 
Can I set attributes and relations between classes to deserialize the above-mentioned case? Maybe I have to create separate classes for each content type?

Comment: `DataContractSerializer` doesn't support element polymorphism via changing the element name.  You'll need to change your design or implement `IXmlSerializable` for `Y<TContent>`, the latter of which is a nuisance and not recommended.  Let me know if you want answers for either approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should change my design. The simplest approach would be to create separate classes for each case. Do you have any other idea? I can't change the xml structure.